# getting id from a jsp page using javascript

Tags: java, javascript, jsp

I have a page that contains the following code:

```
<td id="td-id-<%=tdId%>" class="<%

      if (scheduleList.get(key) != null && scheduleList.get(key).length() > 0) {
        if (scheduleList.get(key).contains("RESERVED")) {
          out.print("reserved-schedule");
        } else if (scheduleList.get(key).contains("AVAILABLE")) {
          out.print("open-schedule");
        } else {
          out.print("closed-schedule");
        }
      } else {
        out.print("closed-schedule");
      }

        %>">
      <%-- end of color --%>
      <%-- text inside the box --%>
      <%
        if (scheduleList.get(key) != null && scheduleList.get(key).length() > 0) {
          if (key.contains("RESERVED")) {
            out.print(scheduleList.get(key).split("-")[3]);
          } else if (scheduleList.get(key).contains("AVAILABLE")) {
            out.print(rb.getString("teacher.submit.open.lessons").replace(" lessons", ""));
          } else {
            out.print(rb.getString("teacher.submit.close.lessons").replace(" lessons", ""));
          }
        } else {
          out.print(rb.getString("teacher.submit.close.lessons").replace(" lessons", ""));
        }
        //out.print(" " + cal.getTimeInMillis() / 1000);
      %>
      <input type="hidden" class="td-id" value="<%=tdId%>"/>
      <%out.print(tdId);%>
      <%-- end of text inside the box --%>
    </td>
```

I want to get the id according to which td I will select(it allows you to select single or multiple td), that code is inside a loop that prints 7 td's in 1 row. That includes unique id in each td. How is that possible. Thank you.

Comment: Where is the code for table creation ?

Comment: just to confirm, you need the html table?

Comment: How are you creating the table? Dynamic through scripting or is it static ?

Comment: dynamic through scripting

Comment: I got your code, what is the problem , you are dynamically creating each td with an id right ?

Comment: yes I'm dynamically creating each td with an id

Comment: when you want that id(may be onclicking some button??) and what you going to do with that?